# When using localListen for messages on a client node, which thread pool is used for the executions?

Tags: ignite

Was looking through the docs but didn't see anything specific to determine which ( if any ) of the Ignite thread pools are used when using a localListen. As far as I can tell it's only using 8 threads, but I'm not sure if it's an Ignite threadpool or a java related one. Based on the answer it will help me know how to tune to make sure not too many ( or too few ) messages are handled at the same time. I'm hoping it's a an easy answer for someone who knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be processed by [the system pool](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/thread-pools#section-system-pool). I wouldn't adjust it unless needed. Try to process data as fast as you can within the localListener. If there is a chance that the processing can be blocked or delayed then start a custom pool and hand over the processing to it once the localListener is called.